# how can i swap these two variable

Tags: python, oop, setter

i have to swap the two variable using setter and getter but its giving the same exact answer

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, thing1=0, thing2=0):
        self._thing1 = thing1
        self._thing2 = thing2
    def get_assignThings(self) :
        return self._thing1, self._thing2
    def set_assignThings(self, x, y):
        self._thing1 = x
        x = y
        self._thing2 = y
        
obj = Thing()
obj.set_assignThings(2, 3)
print(obj.get_assignThings())
```

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to set the attributes to the parameters x and y, or are you trying to swap the attributes?

Comment: You aren't swapping anything; the intermediate assignment `x = y` doesn't do anything, because you don't use `x` again.

Comment: A swap would be something like `tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp`, which in Python is more simply written `x, y = y, x`.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 def set_assignThings(self, x, y):        
        self._thing1, self._thing2 = y,x
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order how they are returned or set:
ie here : `return self._thing2, self._thing1`
or `self._thing1 = y`
`self._thing2 = x`

**Full code:**

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, thing1=2, thing2=3):
        self._thing1 = thing1
        self._thing2 = thing2

    def get_assignThings(self):
        return self._thing2, self._thing1

    def set_assignThings(self, x, y):
        self._thing1 = x
        self._thing2 = y


obj = Thing()
obj.set_assignThings(2, 3)
print(obj.get_assignThings())
```

**Out:**

```
(3, 2)
```